# Why dispute Efficate as a word

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

Not a "formal" word, but most of our current day mobile texting is not formal, a whole new evolving language...
I use "Efficate" as:
"... What can I do to best efficate Laura's desired outcome?"

Comment: Why? We've already got a perfectly adequate verb from the same Latin stem, *effect*.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: The question is in the heading but the question mark is absent.

Comment: I voted to close as POB because we now have at least 3 reasons why someone might “dispute” its use: 1. it’s not in the dictionary. 2 we already have a good word for that concept 3 it sounds a lot like another word that doesn’t have pleasant connotations.  (I’d probably use *achieve* in your sentence)

Comment: The  OED does happen to mention a verb spelled *efficiate*; fortunately, it is now considered to be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I think the unpopularity of the word 'efficate' is its close proximity in pronunciation to 'defecate'.

In conversation, it may be misheard or it may attract unwanted smirks and giggles.

Answer (score 0):

In slang usage, you can do as you wish, of course (although even there, there are some generally accepted rules).  *Efficate* certainly doesn't sound like slang, however; it sounds like an attempt to use an elevated word when in fact, the word doesn't exist in English.  (*Efficacy* - the effectiveness of something - certainly does exist, and is reasonably frequently used, and somewhat less commonly, its adjectival form *efficacious* is found.)

In most dialects of English, it would be far more common to simply say: "What can I do to best make Laura's desired outcome happen?"

If your goal is to save bytes and finger strokes in your texting, you'd be far better off to say something like "How can I help Laura?" than to make up new words over which your phone's autocorrect feature is likely to choke.

Comment: Are you using "slang" to mean "casual"?

Comment: @tchrist To mean "very informal", per its dictionary definition.